# Use of 'that is', 'that I' in German

Tags: grammar

> Der Logo Design dieses Unternehmens ist bestehend aus einem visuellen
> System **der** von drei Vierecke zusammengesetzt ist.
>
> Die originelle Inspiration hinter dem Schriftzügen kam aus einem
> Geldwechselautomat **der** ich in einer Brighton Strandpromenade
> Arkade fand.

System in neuter, Geldwechselautomat is masculine. So how do I know what word to use where currently **der** sits. Or can someone point me to the grammar rule I need to learn?

Apologies for the other probable grammar errors.

Comment: https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Relativpronomen.2C_m.2C_f

Comment: Wiktionary doesn't really *explain* relative pronouns in German - The single sentence from Wikipedia *Das Relativpronomen leitet einen Relativsatz ein und trägt die Merkmale von Numerus und Genus des Substantivs, auf das es sich bezieht. Der Kasus des Relativpronomens richtet sich jedoch nach seiner grammatischen Funktion im Relativsatz.* hits it much better.

Comment: @tofro, ich fand die Frage generell schlecht gestellt, eben weil es für eine Antwort nötig gewesen wäre, vollständig zu erklären, wie Relativpronomen funktionieren. Kann man natürlich machen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as follows.

1. Try and break the relative clauses apart into complete, separate  sentences that express the same fact. Your example sentences would then look like (Corrected some mistakes on the fly):

> Das Logo dieses Unternehmens besteht aus einem visuellen System. *Das* visuelle System ist aus drei Vierecken zusammengesetzt.
>
> Die originelle Inspiration hinter den Schriftzügen kam von einem Geldwechselautomat. *Den* Geldwechselautomat fand ich in einer Arkade der Strandpromenade von Brighton.

2. Now go back and re-assemble the sentences into relative clauses, using the article you have used in the split-off relative clause as a relative pronoun and shuffling the predicate around:

> Das Logo dieses Unternehmens besteht aus einem visuellen System, *das* aus drei Vierecken zusammengesetzt ist.
>
> Die originelle Inspiration hinter den Schriftzügen kam von einem Geldwechselautomat, *den* ich in einer Arkade der Strandpromenade von Brighton fand.

Caveat (inspired by @CarstenS): "originell" tends to be a false friend - It does *not* mean "original" (which would be "originär", or better "ursprünglich"), but rather "fancy" or "inventive". Left in here because of missing context.

Comment: This doesn't affect the answer, but *originell* is probably a false friend here

Comment: @CarstenS Most probably yes - But I was not 100% sure, so decided to leave it.